# Efficiently matchmaking players in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a game that requires player matchmaking i.e. putting 2 players into 1 battle room.

While there are few players online in the game this is not an issue, however if we assume scenario of 1,000,000 players online at a time, who are all trying to matchmake, then picture becomes more complex.

Assuming following flow

[image]

My first instinct was to

1. When player clicks "play" call cloud function that checks if "open" battle room exists.
2. If there is one open, place player in it and start the battle or set battle to be active.
3. In case there wasn't an open room, we create new one and wait for another player to join.

However I see a lot of issues here given that we have 1,000,000 players who would be performing this action. For example, while performing step 2 and setting room to be "active" we might be pushing more players into it during the time those requests resolve?

Comment: hi, have you done this ?? i m also working on this but not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deal with concurrency, I think you should use transactions to perform this action (adding a player to a room). That way, you ensure to check if the room is still open before adding a player in it. If 2 players start a matchmaking at the same time and find the same room, then only one single player will be added to that room
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand I can suggest One way to make it easier is have state of a user itself instead of calling cloud function to create room

1. Make user state like active, online, offline. When a user press play set its state active.
2. Call a query to fetch user where state == active , limit to 5(example).
3. start a transaction to match it with first user if succeed change status to playing for both else if failed ( you got matched to someone else or player you were trying with got matched to someone) check next player.
4. If during this you should be always observing your own state if it changes to playing because someone else matched to you then straight head to game.